# MYSQL inserting to a new row with in one query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql9 = "INSERT INTO Already_Selected (AL_S) VALUES ('$text4, $text3, $text2, $text1, $text')";
```

so basically my issue is when inserting in to the database `$text, $text1, $text2` etc all insert in the same row so the look like this in the database

`B20609, B30329, A10427, A10303, A10201`

i need them to insert on a new row each time so they look like

```
B20609
B30329
A10427
```

So they look like that in the database. Basically at each comma i need a new row

Comment: Please be aware of the fact that this query is open to SQL injections!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$sql9 = "INSERT INTO Already_Selected (AL_S)
  VALUES ('$text4'), ('$text3'), ('$text2'), ('$text1'), ('$text')";
```